# Image is uploaded but unable getting entry in database Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminform

I am performing image uploading task in admin form Magento 2. I can choose the image and also can upload it in my module but I'm not getting the entry of that image into my database's table field.

[image]
This is my controller.

```
<?php
namespace Webkul\Grid\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action

{

protected $_mediaDirectory;
protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
) 
{
    $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    /*For Image Upload*/

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

    try{
        $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('mycustomfolder/');        
        /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'content']);
        /** Allowed extension types */
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'doc']);
        /** rename file name if already exists */
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        /** upload file in folder "mycustomfolder" */
        $result = $uploader->save($target);

        if ($result['file']) 
        {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('File has been successfully uploaded')); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
        '*/*/upload', ['_secure'=>$this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
    );
    /*For Image Upload Finished*/ 

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    if (!$data) {
        $this->_redirect('grid/grid/addrow');
        return;
    }
    try {
        $rowData = $this->_objectManager->create('Webkul\Grid\Model\Grid');
        $rowData->setData($data);
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $rowData->setEntityId($data['id']);
        }
        $rowData->save();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Row data has been successfully saved.'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
    $this->_redirect('grid/grid/index');
}

/**
 * Check Category Map permission.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Webkul_Auction::add_auction');
}
}
```

Comment: image is move in your directory ?

Comment: Yes image is moving into pub/media/mycustomfolder.

Comment: what is image field name in database? is that `content`?

Comment: Yes it's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code before `$rowData->setData($data);`

```
$data['content'] = $data['content']['name'];
```

Flush cache after update this

Comment: No, now I also unable to even insert into database.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved my issue.
My controller.
Save.php

```
<?php
namespace Webkul\Grid\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

protected $_mediaDirectory;
protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
) 
{
    $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    /*For Image Upload*/

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

    try{
        //echo "hi";die;
        $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('mycustomfolder/');

        $targetOne = "mycustomfolder/";
        /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'content']);
        /** Allowed extension types */
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'doc']);
        /** rename file name if already exists */
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        /** upload file in folder "mycustomfolder" */
        $result = $uploader->save($target);
        /*If file found then display message*/
        if ($result['file']) 
        {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('File has been successfully uploaded')); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }

    /*For Image Upload Finished*/ 

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    $data['content'] = $targetOne.$result['file'];

    if (!$data) {
        $this->_redirect('grid/grid/addrow');
        return;
    }
    try {

        $rowData = $this->_objectManager->create('Webkul\Grid\Model\Grid');

        $rowData->setData($data);

        if (isset($data['id'])) 
        {
            $rowData->setEntityId($data['id']);
        }
        $rowData->save();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Row data has been successfully saved.'));
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
    $this->_redirect('grid/grid/index');

    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
        '*/*/upload', ['_secure'=>$this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
    );
}

/**
 * Check Category Map permission.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Webkul_Auction::a    namespace Webkul\Grid\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{dd_action');
}
}
```

My Layout file.

```
    <?php $collection = $block->getCollectionFor();

$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); //instance of\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager
$storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
$mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);


 ?>
<?php foreach($collection as $data)
        {   
            $values = $data['content'];
            ?><img src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.$values; ?>" heigh="50" width="150"/><?php
        }
?>
```